# How to secure Laravel without using Document Root folder to public

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel

How can I secure Laravel without using Document Root folder to public. Let's assume I have several instances of Laravel running in one directory.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use a htaccess file to secure all directories. This is the file I used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app - [F]
RewriteRule ^bootstrap - [F]
RewriteRule ^config - [F]
RewriteRule ^database - [F]
RewriteRule ^resources - [F]
RewriteRule ^storage - [F]
RewriteRule ^tests - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^public /index.php [L,NC]

<FilesMatch "^\.|server\.php|artisan|\.(md|js|json|lock|yml|xml|sh)">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```